# Should data access in Web applications run on different Tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a series of ASP.Net Web Api services that basically get data from a database and return it.

We decided for now to reuse previous poorly written Data Access Objects (let's call them `PoorDAO`) that use ADO.Net to call stored procedures in the database.

One improvement in the future will be to rewrite that data access layer to benefit from [Async data calls](http://www.itworld.com/development/405462/why-you-should-use-async-tasks-net-45-and-entity-framework-6) with Entity Framework.

Because of this, we decided to wrap the `PoorDAO`'s in Repositories implementing an interface that exposes asynchronous methods. The idea is to keep the same interfaces for future EF asynchronous repositories :

```cs
// future common interface
public interface ICountryRepository
{
  Task<Country> GetAllCountries();
}

// current implementation hiding a PoorDAO in shame
public class CountryRepository : ICountryRepository
{
  public Task<Country> GetAllCountries()
  {
    var countries = PoorCountryDAO.GetAllcountries(); // poor static API call

    // some data transformation ...

    return Task.FromResult(result);
  }
}
```

What we have here is basically a synchronous operation hiding in asynchronous clothing. This is all fine, but my question is : while we're at it, wouldn't it be better to make the method entirely async and call `await Task.Run(() => poorCountryDAO.GetAllcountries())` instead of just `poorCountryDAO.GetAllcountries()` ?

As far as I can tell, this would free up the IIS thread the Web Api service HTTP request is currently running on, and create or reuse another thread. This thread would be blocked waiting for the DB to respond instead of the IIS thread being blocked. *Is that any better resource wise ? Did I totally misunderstand or overinterpret how Task.Run() works ?*

**Edit :** I came across [this article](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronous-database-calls-with-task-based-asynchronous-programming-model-tap-in-asp-net-mvc-4) which claims that in some cases, asynchronous database calls can result in an 8 fold performance improvement. His scenario is very close to mine. I can't get my head around how that could be possible given the answers here and am a bit perplexed about what to do...

Answer (score 6):

> Is that any better resource wise?

No; it's provably worse. The existing `Task.FromResult` and `await` is the best solution.

`Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, and `Task.Start` should not be used in an ASP.NET application. They steal threads from the *same* thread pool that ASP.NET uses, causing extra thread switches. Also, if they are long-running, they will mess with the default ASP.NET thread pool heuristics, possibly causing it to create and destroy threads unnecessarily.

Comment: That seems to make perfect sense but some people argue it is not always the case (see my edit). I'm a bit confused right now :/

Comment: Using asynchronous database calls is completely different than using `Task.Run` to wrap synchronous database calls. Asynchronous database calls are great, and should be used (you mention you're already planning to do this in the future). But you should not use `Task.Run` to wrap synchronous database calls.

Comment: Asynchronous database calls : is that what the author does with a simple `AsynchronousProcessing = true` on a SqlCommand ? The connection between that and EF's async query and save is still not clear to me. Documentation gives very little info about the implications of `AsynchronousProcessing = true` and the article's author doesn't respond, do you know where I could find more internal details on how the SQL server data provider handles that option ?

Comment: Asynchronous db calls are things like `ExecuteReaderAsync`. [`AsynchronousProcessing` isn't necessary anymore in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It's the same thing, you're locking up a thread while releasing another one. In theory performance is the same, although it will actually be slightly worse because of the overhead of context switching

Answer (score 0):

A few points: first, for `await Task.Start(() => poorCountryDAO.GetAllcountries())`, `Task.Start(() => poorCountryDAO.GetAllcountries())` already gives you a task, so you should just return that instead rather than awaiting.

Note that in any case, the fact that this method's `Task` is really synchronous is an implementation detail.  There may be a temptation to wrap the `GetAllCountries()` call itself in a background thread, but that's a bad idea.

In all of these cases, you're still going to be stuck wasting a thread.  The scenario you desire where you free up the IIS thread completely requires the use of "Overlapped IO" for the database calls (as per your link).

Basically, in these cases right now, one way or another, a thread (either the main thread or a worker thread) are going to block when they call `PoorCountryDAO.GetAllcountries()`.  However, when you switch to the asynchronous DB calls, they will no longer burn a thread at all.  If, however, the caller uses its own Task.Run, that will now come back to bite you.

Comment: What you suggest makes no difference at all, it's probably even worse.

Comment: @MarkSowul "poorCountryDAO.GetAllcountries()) already gives you a task" : it might not be clear from my description but no, that method isn't asynchronous. It's an old vanilla static method from a legacy class we have.

Comment: @guillaume31 I conflated the client calling the web service, with the web service calling the API; see edit