# Are there any benefits of using a task if we synchronously wait for the result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a Partial Action that needs to call an async method that returns Task from a DB Call. Since I can't have an async Partial Action I need to wait for the task to complete:

```
public ActionResult TopMenu()
{
  var topMenuTask = Task.Run<IEnumerable<TopMenuItem>>( () => 
    { return _menuService.GetTopMenu(); });
  topMenuTask.Wait();

  //view model population code goes here

  return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

It is my understanding the benefit of doing an async DB (IO) call is we are requeueing the thread to the thread pool so it can serve more requests while the IO is finishing, but wouldn't this be a moo point in this case as we are synchronously waiting for it?

Answer (score 4):

I assume from your problem description that `GetTopMenu` returns a `Task`, and thus [should actually be called `GetTopMenuAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

In this case, your best option is probably what you are already doing:

```
public ActionResult TopMenu()
{
  var topMenuTask = Task.Run(() => _menuService.GetTopMenuAsync());
  var topMenu = topMenuTask.Result;

  //view model population code goes here

  return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

> It is my understanding the benefit of doing an async DB (IO) call is we are requeueing the thread to the thread pool so it can serve more requests while the IO is finishing, but wouldn't this be a moo point in this case as we are synchronously waiting for it?

Correct. By wrapping the (asynchronous) DB access within a (synchronous) partial action, the code is nullifying the benefits of `async`.

This is a limitation of the platform (ASP.NET MVC). Please vote [on the issue](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601) and [on uservoice](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3233329-support-asynchronous-child-actions).

Comment: According to @Noseratio we shouldn't run Task.Run in ASP.NET. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, that's a good general rule. If you have a *synchronous* `GetTopMenu` then you should use that instead. My code example is assuming that you *only* have an asynchronous `GetTopMenuAsync` available, and you *have* to use it within a child action.

Comment: Stephen, are you suggesting keeping `Task.Run` here to avoid a potential deadlock situation? I think @JonasStawski may want to try calling `_menuService.GetTopMenu[Async]().Result` directly first and see if that works. It should if there is no `await` anywhere in the chain of calls inside it.

Comment: @Noseratio: I could go either way on this one. `Task.Run` has the benefit of being a bit more resilient if the code changes in the future; but `Result` is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You will summon a thread from the thread pool that will execute that logic but the web request thread will be blocked waiting for the result. So no, there is no benefit.

Why can´t you do this?:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TopMenu()
{
    var topMenu = await Task.Run<IEnumerable<TopMenuItem>>( () => { return _menuService.GetTopMenu(); });

    //view model population code goes here

    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

Another option is to use the classic async MVC way, but you have to derive your controller from `AsyncController` rather than `Controller`:

```
  public void TopMenuAsync()
  {
      AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
      Task.Run<IEnumerable<TopMenuItem>>(() => { return _menuService.GetTopMenu(); })
          .ContinueWith(t =>
          {
              AsyncManager.Parameters["topMenu"] = t.Result;
              AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
          });
  }

  public ActionResult TopMenuCompleted(TopMenuItem topMenu)
  {
      //view model population code goes here

      return PartialView(viewModel);
  }
```

Comment: From the question: “I can't have an async Partial Action”. I assumed that was simply a limitation of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Is my statement not true? I tried using async on the Action, but it fails because of the reasons mentioned in the question. The partial action is being called with Html.RenderPartial

Comment: I tried with `@Html.Partial` and it worked fine. I will try with `@Html.RenderPartial` later on.

Comment: @vtortola, are you saying that `Html.Partial` in Razor work with async `Task<ActionResult>` partial actions, indeed? Have you tried @Html.RenderPartial too?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET in the fist place. You're still limited by a single HTTP request/response time frame, it won't speed up the content delivery and will just introduce an extra thread switch, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533551/1768303).

So, your action should look like this:

```
public ActionResult TopMenu()
{
  var topMenu = return _menuService.GetTopMenu();

  //view model population code goes here

  return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

If your partial views may take a while to render, consider using a technique like this:

http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/11/13/improve-perceived-performance-of-asp-net-mvc-websites-with-async-partialviews/

Comment: I'm getting an error with your syntax, specifically the `return _menuService.GetTopMenu()`

Comment: @JonasStawski, please refer to @StephenCleary's answer, he explained it better than I could do. If `GetTopMenu` returns a `Task`, see if there's another `Task.Run` wrapper inside it and get rid of it if you have access to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.. and it is generally the reason why you defer the decision of using a `Task` up to the caller, or provide async and non-async versions of the call (e.g: `GetTopMenu` and `GetTopMenuAsync`). If you force the use of an async call then you run into situations just like this.

Your alternative is to load the view and asynchronously make the call via AJAX. You can also give the user visual feedback in this scenario. Utilising `await` in this scenario will free up the worker process for IIS to continue serving requests.